# Create Azure Data Factory pipeline V2 from visual studio

Tags: azure-data-factory

Is there a data factory plugin for visual studio? Is it possible to automate the creation of data factory pipelines using the JSON files in visual studio instead of authoring them on the portal?
What are the other possible options?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no VS plugin for ADF v2 development.
It was available for ADF v1 only